# Inserir gráficos automaticamente no github pages

Tags: github, r, markdown

ao criar um arquivo .md para a pasta _post do github pages com o rstudio os gráficos gerados com os comandos do R devem ser inseridos um a um via o comando:

```
![center](/nome_pasta_imagens_dentro_da_master/nome_da_figura.png)
```

Ou existe alguma forma de renderizar automáticamente os gráficos gerados sem criar um comando para cada um?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada nesse repositório https://github.com/yihui/knitr-jekyll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma forma muito fácil de fazer isso: coloque os códigos das figuras (em R) em um arquivo rmarkdown (Rmd) e compile para o [formato markdown do Github](https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/user/articles/github-flavored-markdown/).

Só para dar um exemplo, vamos criar um arquivo no rstudio a partir de um template compatível com o Github Flavored Markdown (vou me referir a ele como GFM).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo criado é o seguinte:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: github_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## GitHub Documents

This is an R Markdown format used for publishing markdown documents to GitHub. When you click the **Knit** button all R code chunks are run and a markdown file (.md) suitable for publishing to GitHub is generated.

## Including Code

You can include R code in the document as follows:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Veja que há um plot com o comando:

```
plot(pressure)
```

Clique no botão knit

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

que o arquivo será compilado para o markdown, no formato apropriado para o Github.

````
Untitled
================

GitHub Documents
----------------

This is an R Markdown format used for publishing markdown documents to GitHub. When you click the **Knit** button all R code chunks are run and a markdown file (.md) suitable for publishing to GitHub is generated.

Including Code
--------------

You can include R code in the document as follows:

``` r
summary(cars)
```

    ##      speed           dist       
    ##  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
    ##  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
    ##  Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
    ##  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
    ##  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
    ##  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00

Including Plots
---------------

You can also embed plots, for example:

![](github_markdown_files/figure-markdown_github/pressure-1.png)

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Você pode gerar quantas figuras você quiser a partir dos códigos em R que os arquivos em markdown apresentarão as figuras de forma apropriada. É importante notar que, após a compilação, o RStudio cria uma pasta no local com todas as figuras referenciadas no markdown, tal que se você for utilizar esse recurso no Github Pages você deve fazer o upload da pasta também.

Comment: Muito obrigado @FlavioBarros, ajudou muito!